# How can I find and select the quantum backends available in qbraid?

Tags: quantum-computing, qiskit, qbraid

I'm using a qiskit tutorial for qbraid which is a basic hello world. I see that there is the possibility to use other quantum backends rather than qiskit, but there's not a clear path for this in the UI.

Is there a command line or direct way to search the API for other backends?

Comment: Can you link the tutorial for context and reference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the language of qBraid you are looking for ways to expose and select Devices. One of the advantages of qBraid as a platform is the ability to engage with a range of quantum computing platforms, and manage your workload, and they seem to have been adding more providers in the last six months or so.

The [documentation for Devices](https://docs.qbraid.com/en/latest/sdk/devices.html) shows methods for what they call "Unified Device Search". There is a `get_devices` function that returns the platforms as well as their status.

```
from qbraid import get_devices

get_devices()
```

They give examples of running this function with search criteria, such as "search for all gate-based QPUs with at least 7 qubits".

```
get_devices(
    filters={
        "paradigm": "gate-based",
        "type": "QPU",
        "numberQubits": {"$gte": 7},
    }
)
```

This call in Jupyter has a neat table return, and qBraid sidebar.

[image: Jupyter view]

Be sure to check the docs for examples on wrapping these devices and managing workloads.